# Scale a server that has blocking database access by reducing thread resources for non-blocking part

Tags: java, multithreading, server

I want to build a process flow. I have multiple requests to process in a queue. One thread (call it T1) takes the first request start processing it and then passes it to some other thread (from a pool of threads lets call it T2) at a point when it has to do some blocking database access. T1 should get free now to process another request from queue. The blocking database access is done by a thread from T2 pool. Then after the database operation is completed, thread from T2 passes it to a thread T3 which return the processed result of the request and after that gets free to return another result processed by T2.

I want to do this to avoid one thread for one request model as it would bring a lot of context switching overheads and all threads will eventually block on database access and CPU  resources will be wasted at that time. The T1 and T3 threads can be considered as thread pools of size of limited size depending on the cores in the CPU.

I thought about above approach after getting to know about async servelet as after getting the request it does not block the thread and instead a different thread does the job and returns the response later.
Let me know if the process flow I need to build is feasible in java and some resources on how can it be achieved.

Comment: Servlet supports async process since 3.1. A better choice may be spring webflux, which builds in reactor and reactor-netty. We can customize business threadpool and network threadpool easily.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting a single request seems like a nice idea, but to optimize use of resources, I would look for using semaphores and have each request be handled by a different thread.
Try limiting the number of requests with semaphores, and limit the access to resources that can be accessed only one at a time also with semaphores.
Splitting a single request can be a good idea, but I think it is a good idea mostly in the case scenario that you want to save the data inside some files, to lower the memory usage of the threads.
I will try adding some Java code later if I can find my old projects...